# Проблема вызова метода http.delete в Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular2, rest

При исполнении такого кода:

```
deleteMaterialType(id: number)
{
 let link = this.url+'materials-type?id='+id;
 return this.http.delete(link).subscribe((data: Response) => data.json());
}
```

Выполняется HTTP запрос только с методом OPTIONS а не DELETE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас там, случаем, не Cross-Origin запрос? Тогда так и должно быть: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111936/angularjs-performs-an-options-http-request-for-a-cross-origin-resource

Comment: При любом cross origin запросе кроме GET первым посылается OPTIONS, если сервер в ответ не пришлет правильные заголовки в ответе, оригинальный запрос отправлен не будет.

Comment: @Yaant
Так все верно, запрос кросдомений

Comment: @Dimanoid
То есть мне надо на сервере сделать еще один роут на метод OPTIONS и отдавать там "правильные" заголовки? 
И почему POST запрос нормально отработал (по таком же адресу)?

Comment: Ошибся немного. Кроме GET, POST и HEAD.

Comment: Да, нужно отвечать на OPTIONS, в зависимости от потребностей в ответе должны быть заголовки Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers и т.д. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @Dimanoid 
Посоветуйте пожалуйста как лучше и безопаснее сделать:
Так получилось что клиент и сервер будут на отдельных доменах, мне так же писать методы (GET,PUT,POST,DELETE) и отправлять JS -сом, или лучше написать прокси сервис для этого? Или объединить эти два подхода?

Comment: Лично мне кажется, что в плане безопасности разницы нет, а с дополнительным прокси больше возни и меньше надежность.

Answer (score 0):

```
options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json' // Format set to JSON
  })
});

deleteMaterialType(id: number) {
   let link = this.url+'materials-type?id='+id;
   return this.http.delete(link, this.options).subscribe((data: Response) => data.json());
}
```

Передаете заголовок после url адреса